# Find extreme values using lagrange multiplier

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Find the extreme values of $f(x, y)=x^2+2y^2$ on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ using Lagrange's multiplier method.

My attempt:

The constraint function $g$ is $g(x, y)=x^2+y^2-1$. So $\vec\nabla f=\lambda\vec\nabla g$ implies that 
$$2x\vec i+4y\vec j=\lambda(2x\vec i+2y\vec j)\Rightarrow 2x=2x\lambda, 4y=2y\lambda.$$ Now from these, either $x=0, y=0$ which is not a possible solution because it is not on $g(x, y)$. But after this, I could not go further. What should I do next?

Comment: First says $x=0$ or $\lambda=1$. With $\lambda=1$ the second says $y=0$ and from $x^2+y^2=1$ we get $x=\pm1$.

Comment: oh! so $x=0$ also means from $x^2+y^2=1$ that $y=\pm 1$?

Comment: With $(0,1)$ we find $2(0)\vec i+4(1)\vec j=2(2(0)\vec i+2(1)\vec j)$ satisfies $\vec\nabla f=\lambda\vec\nabla g$ for $\lambda=2$ right!

Comment: is $(0, 0)$ minimum as it is not on $g$?

Comment: so minimum at $(\pm 1, 0)$ and maximum at $(0, \pm 1)$.

Comment: yes. respectively $f=1$ and $f=2$.